# Illegal polymorphic or qualified type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, higher-rank-types

Why is Haskell complaining when trying to parse this type signature?

```
f :: (a,s) -> (forall r.(r -> (a,r)),s)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haskell does not support impredicative types, and in particular does not allow `forall` to appear under any type constructor (except `->`).

For example, `Maybe (forall a. a), [forall a. a->a], ((forall a. a), Bool)` are forbidden.

Use a `newtype` wrapper if that's what you want.

```
newtype T = T (forall a. a->a)
foo :: [T] -- OK
foo = [T id]
```

Answer (score 4):

Out of curiosity, what are you trying to use this type for? It looks like the type of a concatenative combinator like `quote` such that `[X] quote == [[X]]` (sometimes called `unit`). In other words, it takes a value atop the stack and wraps it in a function which, when applied, pushes that value to the stack.

Here’s one representation I’ve used in the past for such functions. The `Tupled` type family converts a list of types into a nested tuple to represent a stack.

```
-- Tupled '[t1, t2, ..., tn] s == (t1, (t2, (... (tn, s))))
type family Tupled ts t where
  Tupled '[] t' = t'
  Tupled (t ': ts) t' = (t, Tupled ts t')
```

Using a `newtype` wrapper we can make a function (of a certain input & output arity) that’s polymorphic in the “rest” of the stack.

```
newtype as :-> bs = Fun (forall s. Tupled as s -> Tupled bs s)
```

This is the standard way of hiding *impredicative polymorphism*, that is, using `forall`-quantified types under a type constructor other than a function arrow `(->)`, as you did when you tried to write `(forall r. (r -> (a, r)), s)`. Haskell doesn’t support this directly, but if you use a `newtype` wrapper then the compiler knows exactly when to introduce and eliminate the `forall`.

By unwrapping this `newtype` and applying it to the stack type, we can apply a wrapped function to a stack.

```
apply :: forall z as bs. (as :-> bs) -> Tupled as z -> Tupled bs z
apply (Fun f) as = f @z as
```

The `quote` combinator wraps the top element of the stack in a function:

```
quote :: forall a s. (a, s) -> ([] :-> '[a], s)
quote (a, s) = (Fun $ \s' -> (a, s'), s)
```

`unquote` applies a function on the stack to the rest of the stack.

```
unquote
  :: forall z as bs s
  .  (Tupled as z ~ s)
  => (as :-> bs, s)
  -> Tupled bs z
unquote (f, s) = apply @z f s
```

(Note the equality constraint `Tupled as z ~ s`, which means “The input stack type `s` must begin with the series of types `as`, and whatever remains is called `z`”.)

`add` is the addition operator `(+)` lifted to stacks; it just adds the top two elements of the stack.

```
add :: forall a. (Num a) => '[a, a] :-> '[a]
add = Fun $ \ (x, (y, s)) -> (x + y, s)
```

Now, quoting and unquoting an element leaves it unchanged:

```
unquote (quote ("hello", ()) == ("hello", ())
```

The addition function can be applied directly…

```
apply add (1, (2, ())) == (3, ())
```

…Or placed on the stack and then applied.

```
unquote (add, (1, (2, ()))) == (3, ())
```

This requires the following extensions:

- `DataKinds` to allow type-level lists of types
- `RankNTypes` and `ScopedTypeVariables` to allow explicit `forall`s and bring type variables into scope so we can refer to them with `TypeApplications`, because we need `AllowAmbiguousTypes` to defer specifying the “stack” type until a call site, as in `apply @z f as`
- `TypeFamilies` to enable the `Tupled` type family
- `TypeOperators` to give the nice symbolic name `:->` to wrapped function types